# PDF downloading adding blank pages in between on Apple devices

Tags: javascript, pdf, vuejs3

When I download a PDF from windows/linux/android everything is working fine, but when I download using iphone/ipad/mac it adds a blank page after every alternative page

This is my code for downloading the pdf. I am using vue 3

```
async function setDownloadPreview(document){
        selectPDFTemplate.value.selectedMagnet=document
        try{
            if ( !document.contentDownloaded ){
                // toast( "Loading pdf content", toastType.INFO )
                let response = await api.get("/doc/document", {
                    params: { leadMagnetId: document._id },
                })
                if (response.data.success){
                    document.blocks = response.data.blocks
                    document.pdfTemplateUrl = response.data.pdfTemplateUrl
                    document.templateImgName = response.data.templateImgName
                    docEditorRef.value.loadContent(response.data.blocks)
                    if (response.data.pdfTemplateUrl){
                        let imageResponse = await fetch(response.data.pdfTemplateUrl)
                        let blob = await imageResponse.blob()
                        blobToBase64(blob).then( res =>{
                            document.pdfTemplateUrl = res
                            document.contentDownloaded = true
                            nextTick( ()=>{ window.print() } )
                        })
                    }else{
                        nextTick( ()=>{ window.print() } )
                    }

                }else{
                    toast('Failed to get PDF data', toastType.WARNING)
                }
            }else{
                docEditorRef.value.loadContent(document.blocks)
                nextTick( ()=>{ window.print() } )
            }
        }catch(err){
            console.log(err)
        }
    }
```